# How to fetch entries/values from database to a jsp page one by one?

Tags: java, sql, database, jsp

I have a table in Microsoft SQL server Management Studio with two columns title and data and each column has 10 enteries.
I have a jsp page on which i want to display different database entries of the column title in different blocks. 
Now what code i should write that i get each entry in each block?
On my jsp page i wrote:

```
<%  
Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
Connection cn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:ablogs", "sa", "pretty");
Statement stmt = cn.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select title from Postdata"); %>
 <table>
<tbody>
 <% while (rs.next()) {%>
<tr>
<td>
<%=rs.getString(1)%>
</td>
</tr>
<%}%>
</tbody>
</table>
```

through this code i get all entries at one time but i want to get values one by one in diffrent blocks.

Comment: That's too broad for SO. Show us what you've attempted so far and what you think about it.

Comment: can you please edit that into your question?

Comment: Actually the code is just a part of my project. I am trying to use jquery accordion in which i want 2 fetch data values from database. hope u r getting what i mean 2 say.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please ensure that you

1. Use [PreparedStatement](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) instead of Statement
2. Don't write extensive Java code inside JSPs (Strict no for database
   code!)

Assuming you'll change the above later (and if I have understood you correctly), you might want to do it like this:

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select name, title, amount from Postdata"); %>
<table>
    <tbody>
    <% while (rs.next()) {%>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <%=rs.getString("name")%>
        </td>
        <td>
          <%=rs.getString("title")%>
        </td>
        <td>
          <%=rs.getString("amount")%>
        </td>
      </tr>
    <%}%>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: For the given SQL statement using a PreparedStatement does not make any difference as no Parameters are used. +1 for mentioning that SQL statements should not be put into a JSP

Comment: It's good practice to use prepared statements so better to get into the habit of it. Break a rule for good reason today and you'll do it for a bad reason tomorrow...